# How to send form's action to ajax in vue

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2

Working with Larave 5.4, I have a table built with vue.

Each row in the table has this form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm" class="status-form" action="'/orders/' + row.Id + '/edit'" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="status" value="2">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sent</button>
</form>
```

My Route:
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController', ['except => show']);

When the Sent button is clicked, I want to submit the form with AJAX.

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PATCH",
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') },
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: { 'status': 2 },
  success: function(data) {
    alert($(this).attr('action'));
  }
});
```

When I click the Sent button, I get this in Firebug:

PATCH http://highland.local/orders 405 Method Not Allowed

It looks like, it does not get the form's action correctly.
How do I get the form's action from the form, in the ajax call?

Comment: That response is from your server, do you have your route verb set correctly? Also, why on earth are you making ajax requests with jquery when you're using vue?

Comment: The way you write you action, is that even a valid syntax and is that what you want?
`"'/orders/' + row.Id + '/edit'"`?

Comment: Joe, I'm new to laravel and vue. Looking through lots of posts, that's one of the ways I found how to do it, don't know another way. If you can show me, I'll be most grateful. I'm trying to find a way for days...

aks, the action should be: "orders/{{ row.Id }}/edit" where row.Id is the order id. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The only time you will get a `405 Method Not Allowed` response from Laravel is if you attempt to use a HTTP method that is not defined on a route.

For example attempting to make a `POST` request to a `GET` route.

In your case you will require `Route::patch( '/orders/{id}/edit', 'contoller@method' );` in your API routes file.

Comment: Joe, I have this route: Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController', ['except => show']); is that not good?

Comment: I tend to define my routes individually, so I have no idea if Route::resource creates a PATCH route, you can check though by doing `php artisan route:list` and seeing if a PATCH route is defined in the list.

Comment: | PUT|PATCH | orders/{order}| orders.update | App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@update

Comment: That isn't for the same route though? there is no /edit?

Comment: As far as I understand, edit goes to PATCH automatically with resource route. It works for me on a different controller/view situation where I don't use vue.

Comment: I am so confused, trying to solve issues with ajax and vue with laravel for days. Willing to pay for someone to sit with me on skype/TeamViewer and help me code it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139357/discussion-between-sigal-zahavi-and-joe).